# Run a Go Server on Codenvy Environment

Tags: go, codenvy

I'm trying to use Codenvy to develop Go server apps, but I don't know how to run. 
I have already created the project and choose the Web Go runner environment. 
But when I run it, the project run in a different URL port that I have defined.

Have some way to not use an **http port** an use a dynamic port?

```
http.ListenAndServe("{get_url_port}", nil)
```

> instead

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

Comment: Are you looking for environment parameter  option ?

Comment: @MIkCode Yep... I would like to know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process runs in a container, and port 8080 is mapped to a random port each time the app start. So, it's a different port each time. However, the same internal port - as the app runs in a Docker container.

Can you elaborate and give more details?

Comment: Really thanks! That solved my doubt. I wasn't understanding. @kalrsson